# Canon iP7200 shows constant orange light and does nothing

Tags: printer

At home I have a Canon iP7200 printer which refuses to work. As soon as I turn the device on, the white power light comes on as well as the orange status light. The orange light does NOT flash (so none of the flash codes help) and stays on constantly. The printer doesn't respond to anything - not software, not buttonpushes (even the power button does nothing) and can basically only be turned off by pulling the power.

This started since I changed the empty ink containers with new non-Canon ink containers. However, the new ink containers come from a company who actually bought one of the Canon plants, so the containers should contain the same chips as the Canon ones (that's at least what they guaranteed me). Unfortunately I can't return them because I waited too long to install them in my printer.

Sometimes I'm able to turn the printer on and print, but then the next time I turn it on to print, the orange light comes on again. I've found a few mentions online that a constant orange light means a hardware fault, but because the printer has worked perfectly in between showing orange lights, I thinks this is not the case.

Does anybody know what I should do next? Any way to reset the printer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Sometimes I'm able to turn the printer on and print" tells me there's something we're missing, some data point that hasn't been noticed.  Perhaps the connection between the third-party ink chip and its mate on the printer isn't pressing consistently.

Comment: Can you try to remove the foreign ink and/or put in the old one simply as a point of determining of the are the culprit? Based on your story it seems to have all started from that point, so process-of-elimination...

Comment: Download and read the owners manual for troubleshooting tips.....https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-single-function/ip-series/ip7220?tab=manuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unplug the printer. Hold down both the orange and the power button, and put the plug in again. The power button should then turn on and the orange button remain off.
This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your effort and input, but unfortunately I cannot test your solution anymore. By now I've long given up op this printer, bought a new one and disassembled the old one for parts... I'll accept your answer because it will probably help in most cases, but I'm pretty sure I've tried that combination on my printer back when I was still trying to fix it. Anyway, thank you for your answer, and welcome!